# How high will this rocket be, when MECO occurs?

Tags: rockets, spacecraft, physics, rocket-equation, rocket-explosion

Find the altitude of the rocket at the time of engine cut-off.

- Rocket Mass = 369208 kg,
- Rocket Area = 391 m2,
- Fuel = 170697 L,
- Fuel density = 21 kg/l,
- Exhaust Speed = 1338 m/s,
- Exhaust Area = 164 m2

Comment: To find out the height the rocket will go, you need to know how fast it can get. To find that out, you need to provide a bit more information. The ISP, mass-flowrate, density and weight of the fuel. With that information, we can find out the delta v it has with the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation. Then you need to find out the acceleration and the time it will fly. Once you did that, you can calculate the height it will be when the engines cut off

Comment: If this is anything to do with a real rocket something is up with the source numbers since fuel density is higher than lead, exhaust area is 14 meters across so rather larger than any real rocket flown and the exhaust velocity rather low.

Comment: For help with homework, please show what you have done so far.